# how to Check if file(html) exist in clientbin

Tags: silverlight-4.0

how to check that html file exist in clientbin or in other folder in silverlight 4 
in-browser application

Answer (score 2):

Silverlight application is client side application. You can check only URL accessibility **or** write a web service that provide this information to your application